# Can't add my GSuite account to my personal Gmail account

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, pop3

We can't add our GSuite account to my personal Gmail account (Check mail from other accounts: POP, IMAP and SMTP)

- I'm using POP server: pop.gmail.com and Port: 995 with SSL ON
- I'm 100% sure my login and password are correct
- I did enable POP in my Workspace Gmail account settings and the admin of the G Suite admin account also confirmed POP and IMAP are enabled and Less secure app access is also enabled..

I have tried every suggestion and solution from this "help center" and I am not able to add my GSuite address as an alternative to my personal Gmail.
I have tried using pop.gmail.com, port 995, SSL and use your full G Suite email address, including the domain, as the username and immediately get

Server denied POP3 access for the given username and password.
Server returned error: "[AUTH] Username and password not accepted.

The GSuite after login admin, POP access is enabled and Less secure app access is also enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You login to the admin panel, click on users, click on a users name, then security, and turn off the login challenge for 10 mins - then they can add their GSuite as a pop account to their personal Gmail.